# How can I know that the activity is return from system setting page?

Tags: android

The main activity is :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.logo);

    Tools.checkNetword(LogoActivity.this);


}
```

when the activity starts ,it check out where there's availabe network

```
public static void checkNetword(final Context context) {
    if (!Tools.isNetworkAvailabe(context)) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setIcon(R.drawable.hi).setTitle(R.string.logo_dialog_title).setMessage(R.string.set_network)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        //跳转到设置界面
                        context.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                ((Activity)context).finish();
            }
        }).create().show();
    }
}
```

so the user may click positive button ,and then they are brougt to the system setting page.
when they reset the network and click back button. they go back to the activity.
so what should i do?that i want to go on check if the network is ok.
use onrestart method? it seems no work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the method `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)` and then implement `onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)`
. Read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)